# How to change social icon color when move with mouse over them?

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, move, mousehover

I have one issue with [my site](http://deilbeatz.com/). I have social icons bar into my site, and want to change color when move with mouse over it.

I talking about this part:

[image]

and want to make like was in this [site](http://www.superstaro.com/):

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `.aio-tooltip:hover .aio-icon { background: blue; }`

Comment: Yes that is for one circle, but what about others? every circle have different colour, as you noticed.

Comment: either try to figure it out on your own, or create a working demo on SO of everything you have currently instead of linking to a 3rd party site. Linking to your personal site doesn't benefit the other users of SO.

Comment: I tryed, but on every circle give me blue colour. How to change to have different colour? So what is wrong with linking demo site? Its nice to show what i need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the hover selector, but for different colors for each link, you need to put the classname for the link before the icon class like so:

```
.58ae1dbc7fa2c .aio-icon:hover {
      border-color: blue;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

You could change "blue" for whatever shade of blue that you'd like.

You could also add use the transition property to have the color fade in and out on hover like this:

```
.58ae1dbc7fa2c .aio-icon:hover {
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Hi !

`aio-icon:hover {
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}`

but how to have different color on every circle?

Comment: I check it, but dont make any change. without class `.58ae1dbc7fa2c` change blue on every circle.

Comment: you would have to use the class for each <a> that is wrapping each icon, for instance the class for the <a> wrapping the YouTube icon is 58ae1dbc7fa2c and the class for the <a> that is wrapping the Instagram icon is 58ae1dbc7f982 . So you would have to write code for each icon, using the class name for it's <a> wrapper before the aio-icon class.

Comment: class is named: `aio-tooltip 58ae22d650628` for facebook for example.

Comment: you don't need to use the aio-tooltip class, you would just use .58ae22d650628 .aio-icon:hover { code here} for Facebook, then use .58ae1dbc7fa2c .aio-icon:hover { code here} for YouTube etc

Comment: I inserted 

`.58ae1dbc7fa2c .aio-icon:hover {
  border-color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}`

into CustomCSS, but i dont see any changes when move under circle.

Answer (score 0):

This is worknig sollution that i do myself.

```
  div.aio-icon:hover.advanced.faceboook {
  border-color: #3b5996;
  background-color: #3b5996;
  }
  div.aio-icon:hover.advanced.twitter {
  border-color: #29c5f6;
  background-color: #29c5f6;
  }
  div.aio-icon:hover.advanced.instagram {
  border-color: #b16c4f;
  background-color: #b16c4f;
  }
  div.aio-icon:hover.advanced.youtube{
  border-color: #f0251d;
  background-color: #f0251d;
  }
 div.aio-icon:hover.advanced.soundcloud{
  border-color: #ff6d00;
  background-color: #ff6d00;
  }
```

i inserted proper class to every element.